# Hexo "layout: false" still tampers with DOCTYPE

Tags: html, frontend, web-frontend, static-site, hexo

[image]

Above image describes my problem, but I'm trying to host a small SPA within my Hexo blog as a "page". Whenever I try to type the initial HTML I need to get started, even with "layout false", it still changes my DOCTYPE tag. I'm assuming because of the symbols "

I was hoping as mentioned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnhPL.png) that since my "layout: false" is set, none of my HTML would be affected by the fact that it's written in a markdown file.

Is there a much simpler approach to this that I'm not considering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html

See the "Escape Contents" section. Solved.